# Django image upload works in local environment but not on Amazon EC2 running nginx

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, uwsgi, django-forms

I am trying to upload an image using a Django ModelForm. Everything works fine on my home computer, so the problem is probably not in the template or view function. However, when running on nginx + uwsgi + Amazon EC2 instance the image file is not uploaded.

1) I get no error in the nginx error.log or in the browser.

2) PIL has JPEG support.

3) form.save() saves the correct filename in the model instance and the form validates. It even recognizes conflicting filenames in the folder.

4) The media folders have 777 permissions.

5) Images uploaded via FTP work fine so the media files are served correctly by nginx.

6) The field in the model is as simple as 
      img = models.ImageField('Kuvatiedosto',upload_to="images")

I don't know where to look for the error anymore.

SOLVED: My media root was not in line with the media settings of nginx. So the files got uploaded all the time, just not where I expected...

Comment: There is no error there either. POST is logged as if nothing is wrong.